# Why can the first-letter pseudo-element only be applied to block-level elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Today I have learnt this rule, so I would like to know the reason behind it.
Why would it matter if the text is inside block or inline element?

Comment: You'd have to ask the w3.org why.

Comment: I can see a lot of implementation issues like when you make the first letter floating. If the element is an inline one, we will have a strange result

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo/#first-letter-application

Comment: To be precise, it can only be applied to block container boxes, which means that an inline-block - which is an inline-level block container - can contain a ::first-letter.